# Selecting multiple images and setting to a gridView

Tags: java, android

This is probably the worst way to go about this but I'm currently stuck and just going for it. I currently have an Activity where I select multiple images from a GridView from the phone itself. I'm now trying to display it in my MainActivity in another GridView. I've see a lot of people doing this in a LinearLayout but I would really prefer another GridView. Is there an easy way to do so? I've tried to display the ImageAdapter again but it is null.

Here is the Activity where I select the images:

```
public class CustomGalleryActivity extends Activity {

    private GridView grdImages;
    private Button btnSelect;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    private String[] arrPath;
    private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
    private int ids[];
    private int count;


    /**
     * Overrides methods
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_gallery);
        grdImages= (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grdImages);
        btnSelect= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelect);

        final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, orderBy);
        int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
        this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
        ids = new int[count];
        this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
            imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
            ids[i] = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
            int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
        }

        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
        grdImages.setAdapter((ListAdapter) imageAdapter);
        imagecursor.close();


        btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
                int cnt = 0;
                String selectImages = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    if (thumbnailsselection[i]) {
                        cnt++;
                        selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";
                    }
                }
                if (cnt == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select at least one image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {

                    Log.d("SelectedImages", selectImages);
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.putExtra("data", selectImages);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
        super.onBackPressed();

    }

    /**
     * Class method
     */

    /**
     * This method used to set bitmap.
     * @param iv represented ImageView
     * @param id represented id
     */

    private void setBitmap(final ImageView iv, final int id) {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                iv.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
        }.execute();
    }


    /**
     * List adapter
     * @author tasol
     */

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ImageAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public int getCount()
        {
            return count;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gallery_item, null);
                holder.imgThumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumb);
                holder.chkImage = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkImage);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.chkImage.setId(position);
            holder.imgThumb.setId(position);
            holder.chkImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    int id = cb.getId();
                    if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                        cb.setChecked(false);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                    } else {
                        cb.setChecked(true);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            holder.imgThumb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int id = holder.chkImage.getId();
                    if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                        holder.chkImage.setChecked(false);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                    } else {
                        holder.chkImage.setChecked(true);
                        thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            try {
                setBitmap(holder.imgThumb, ids[position]);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
            }
            holder.chkImage.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
            holder.id = position;
            return convertView;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Inner class
     * @author tasol
     */
    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgThumb;
        CheckBox chkImage;
        int id;
    }


}
```

This is where I currently display them into a LinearLayout:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE){
            imagesPathList = new ArrayList<String>();
            String[] imagesPath = data.getStringExtra("data").split("\\|");

            try{
                lnrImages.removeAllViews();
            }catch (Throwable e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i=0;i<imagesPath.length;i++){
                imagesPathList.add(imagesPath[i]);
                yourbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagesPath[i]);
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(yourbitmap);
                imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                lnrImages.addView(imageView);
                gridView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) imageAdapter);
            }
            for (int a = 0; a < imagesPath.length; a++)
            {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured this out a long time ago but i figure i should put an answer here for anyone else to use.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE)
        {
            if (adapter != null)
            {
                adapter.clear();
                adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, R.id.grdImages, items);
                gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            imagesPath = data.getStringExtra("data").split("\\|");

            for (int i=0; i<imagesPath.length; i++)
            {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagesPath[i]);
                items.add(bitmap);
            }

            adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, R.id.grdImages, items);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```